# conditionally sort array of string

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting

i have an array

```
[['Part', 'create'], ['Part', 'update'], ['Part', 'delete'], ['Part', 'release'], ['Plan', 'create'], ['Plan', 'update'], ['Plan', 'delete'], ['Plan', 'release'], ['Inspection', 'create'], ['Inspection', 'update'], ['Inspection', 'delete'], ['Inspection', 'release'], ['User', 'create'],['User', 'update']]
```

i want it to be sorted in order of **Part, Plan, Inspection** and **create, update, delete, release**

the way i want it to be sorted in the above order is cause

```
Part 
  has_many plans
Plan 
  belongs_to :part
  has_many inspections
Inspection
  belongs_to :plan
```

i have implemented dynamic roles and permissions using cancan. the user needs to be assigned permissions for the actions(create, update, delete, release) and the order of display of the 
 SubjectClass(Part, Plan, Inspection, User) must be as their relationship.

when i used **sort**, i get

```
a.sort
 => [["Inspection", "create"], ["Inspection", "delete"], ["Inspection", "release"], ["Inspection", "update"], ["Part", "create"], ["Part", "delete"], ["Part", "release"], ["Part", "update"], ["Plan", "create"], ["Plan", "delete"], ["Plan", "release"], ["Plan", "update"], ["User", "create"], ["User", "update"]] 

a.sort_by{|x, y| x[0] <=> y[0]}
=> [["Part", "create"], ["Part", "update"], ["Part", "delete"], ["Part", "release"], ["Plan", "create"], ["Plan", "update"], ["Plan", "delete"], ["Plan", "release"], ["Inspection", "create"], ["Inspection", "update"], ["Inspection", "delete"], ["Inspection", "release"], ["User", "create"], ["User", "update"]]
```

can **index** method be used in someway? **Also new subjectclasses and actions maybe added later. So sorting order may change.**

Comment: Your edit was a big improvement, including both some background and code that you had tried. +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a = [['Part', 'create'], ['Part', 'update'], ['Part', 'delete'], ['Part', 'release'], ['Plan', 'create'], ['Plan', 'update'], ['Plan', 'delete'], ['Plan', 'release'], ['Inspection', 'create'], ['Inspection', 'update'], ['Inspection', 'delete'], ['Inspection', 'release'], ['User', 'create'],['User', 'update']]
order = [%w{Part Plan Inspection}, %w{create update delete release}]
```

If we assume that all unspecified elements have weight of 999 (such as `User` in your example), this will sort the input array in a given order:

```
a.sort_by{|e| e.zip(order).map{|i,j| j.index(i) || 999}}
=> [["Part", "create"],
 ["Part", "update"],
 ["Part", "delete"],
 ["Part", "release"],
 ["Plan", "create"],
 ["Plan", "update"],
 ["Plan", "delete"],
 ["Plan", "release"],
 ["Inspection", "create"],
 ["Inspection", "update"],
 ["Inspection", "delete"],
 ["Inspection", "release"],
 ["User", "create"],
 ["User", "update"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

taking a clue from the above answer by Miaden, i got a crude implementation working using **index** method

```
a.sort_by{|x, y| ['Part', 'Plan', 'Inspection'].index(x[0]) <=> ['Part', 'Plan', 'Inspection'].index(y[0]) and ['create', 'update', 'delete', 'release'].index(x[1]) <=> ['create', 'update', 'delete', 'release'].index(y[1])}

=> [["Part", "create"], ["Part", "update"], ["Part", "delete"], ["Part", "release"], ["Plan", "create"], ["Plan", "update"], ["Plan", "delete"], ["Plan", "release"], ["Inspection", "create"], ["Inspection", "update"], ["Inspection", "delete"], ["Inspection", "release"], ["User", "create"], ["User", "update"]]
```

it can be further DRY'ed up.